# Showing item price, item id, item name in paypal payment screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used `gem "active_paypal_adaptive_payment"` also set the payment options

```
def checkout
  recipients = [recipientarray]
  response = gateway.setup_purchase(
    :return_url => url_for(:action => 'action', :only_path => false),
    :cancel_url => url_for(:action => 'action', :only_path => false),
    :ipn_notification_url => url_for(:action => 'notify_action', :only_path => false),
    :receiver_list => recipients
  )

  # For redirecting the customer to the actual paypal site to finish the payment.
  redirect_to (gateway.redirect_url_for(response["payKey"]))
end
```

It is redirecting to the paypal payment page.. 
This is the page [image]

In payment summary it does not displaying any item name , price, etc..

can any one suggest how to configure it . Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the "**[ActiveMerchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)**" gem instead - it's updated by Shofify and we've got it to do exactly what you're looking for.

**Problem**

The way to get PayPal to list the items is to use the [ExpressCheckout version](http://codecube.teclacolorida.com/2013/01/21/integration-of-paypal-express-checkout-using-active-merchant/) (I think you're just setting up a peer-to-peer payment), and then pass the items in a hash array. We use a cart, but you may have something else.

The trick with paypal epxress is that you have to get all the totals to add up properly. As you will see in the code I post, we are just using a static shipping value for now (we're still developing this current project), but you can omit shipping if you don't need it.

---

**Solution**

I can only vouch for ActiveMerchant, because that's the only code I've got, but here is what we do:

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
get 'checkout/paypal' => 'orders#paypal_express', :as => 'checkout'
get 'checkout/paypal/go' => 'orders#create_payment', :as => 'go_paypal'
```

**Orders Controller**

```
#controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    #Paypal Express
    def paypal_express
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(total,
          :items => cart_session.build_order, #this is where you create the hash of items
          :subtotal => subtotal,
          :shipping => 50,
          :handling => 0,
          :tax => 0,
          :return_url => url_for(:action => 'create_payment'),
          :cancel_return_url => url_for(:controller => 'cart', :action => 'index')
        )
        redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
    end
#some other stuff is here....
end
```

**Build Items**

```
#models/cart_session.rb (we use this with a cart)
    #Build Hash For ActiveMerchant
    def build_order

        #Take cart objects & add them to items hash
        products = cart_contents

        @order = []
        products.each do |product|
            @order << {name: product[0].name, quantity: product[1]["qty"], amount: (product[0].price * 100).to_i }
        end

        return @order

    end
end
```

Comment: is there any option to send payment directly to receiver paypal email? For this reason i have to work with adaptive gem..

Comment: By paypal email, do you mean "non business" account?

Comment: customer can send the amount to a paypal account via registered email only.. Suppose I am a customer , i want to buy an ad and one paypal email is being added by the seller to forward the purchase amount.. So whenever a customer buys any ad, it will directly redirect to the paypal and pays..

Comment: recipients = [recipientarray] .. does the same thing and take email of the paypl account and splits the amount to these accounts..